# vue import data from outside vue for use in a component, do I need to deep copy

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Imagine I have an object with several props that I want to bring into a variety of vue components' "data" state as sort of a starting point or default state. I want each component to be able to manage its own state going forward from the moment of its initialization.

Something like:

```
import { initialData } from '../../some-data.js'

Vue.component('my-component', {
  data: function () {
    return {
       ...initialData,
       somethingElse: 'hello there",
    }
  },
  template: 'Hi'
})
```

Will Vue make a deep copy of this object so that when it is mutated by user interaction the original object (sitting in some-data.js) will not be mutated or will I need to do that myself using something like:

```
import { initialData } from '../../some-data.js'

Vue.component('my-component', {
  data: function () {
    return {
       ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialData)),
       somethingElse: 'hello there'
    }
  },
  template: 'Hi'
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Vue make a deep copy of this object

A *deep* copy? No, but you will get a shallow copy for that component because you are creating a new object (with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

As with any shallow copy, if `initialData` contains objects then those objects will not be deep copied, but top-level strings and numbers (etc) will be copied.

---

Using `JSON.parse` to do a deep copy is kind of a hack. It's better to use a dedicated deep copy method like lodash [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep). Or you can just write `initialData` as a factory function:

```js
const createInitialData = () => ({
  foo: 'bar',
  nestedObject: {
    blah: 12345
  }
})
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    ...createInitialData(),
    somethingElse: 'hello there'
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use a mixin to set data deep copying or factories is not needed, it's decoupled and also merged in with additional data https://playcode.io/694463/ as long as don't have the same key in data else that key takes precedence

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The mixin still contains a factory function anyway (`data` is a function). The mixin approach is less flexible than just using a plain non-vue-specific function. Depending on the use case it might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try and see what happens?

In `some-data.js` file at the end add something like:

```
setInterval(function() { console.log(initialData) }, 1000);
```

Then when you're importing it, modify something and see what happens with the logs.

Whatever the case is you should probably use Vuex.